# How to query following scenario to count number of users in Django?

Tags: sql, django

I have table in database called `fileupload_share`.

```
+----+----------+----------+----------------+----------------------------------+
| id | users_id | files_id | shared_user_id | shared_date                      |
+----+----------+----------+----------------+----------------------------------+
|  3 |        1 |        1 |              2 | 2013-01-31 14:27:06.523908+00:00 |
|  2 |        1 |        1 |              2 | 2013-01-31 14:25:37.760192+00:00 |
|  4 |        1 |        3 |              2 | 2013-01-31 14:46:01.089560+00:00 |
|  5 |        1 |        1 |              3 | 2013-01-31 14:50:54.917337+00:00 |
```

I want to count the number of `shared_user_id` according to the `file_id`.

For example I want to find with how many users the file with id 1 is shared. The answer is with 2 users`(shared_user_id`). How can I find that in Django?

Answer (score 0):

```
file_id = 2 #Here is your file_id variable
fileupload_share.objects.filter(file_id = file_id)
    .order_by('shared_user_id').distinct('shared_user_id').count()
```

As comments below say this example  doesn't work on MySQL, because of distinct method on field. 
However you can try *danihp*'s method:

```
file_id = 2 #Here is your file_id variable
fileupload_share.objects.filter(file_id = file_id)
    .values_list('shared_user_id', flat=True).distinct().count()
```

Comment: There are two file_id? I am getting undefined variable on the second one.

Comment: on the second file_id you should use your id: 1,2,3 - whatever.

Comment: why order by method with parameter? Should be `.order_by().` it is not?

Comment: danihp, I think, in this example, you shouldn't even use order_by.

Comment: Please add a small explanation of what you are trying to say.

Comment: @ПавелТявин, sure! not needed. But if is included ( to avoid joins ) should be with no parameters.

Comment: I am getting this error: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend

Comment: `fileupload_share.objects.filter(file_id = file_id)
  .values_list('shared_user_id', flat=True).distinct().count()`  Notice that distinct with parameter only runs in progresql.

Comment: user1881957, What db do you use?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the modification. But how can I iterate in template to get sharing of all files?